# Passing a function pointer as template parameter

Tags: c++

For educational purposes I am trying to write my own "ForEach" function:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>


//
// This works
//
template<class Container>
void ForEach_v1(const Container & inContainer, void (*Functor)(const std::string &))
{
    typename Container::const_iterator it = inContainer.begin(), end = inContainer.end();
    for (; it != end; ++it)
    {
        Functor(*it);
    }
}


//
// Does not work
//
template<class Container, class Functor>
void ForEach_v2(const Container & inContainer, Functor inFunctor)
{
    typename Container::const_iterator it = inContainer.begin(), end = inContainer.end();
    for (; it != end; ++it)
    {
        Functor(*it);
    }
}

void PrintWord(const std::string & inMessage)
{
    std::cout << inMessage << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::string> words;
    words.push_back("one");
    words.push_back("two");
    words.push_back("three");

    // Works fine.
    std::cout << "v1" << std::endl;
    ForEach_v1(words, PrintWord);

    // Doesn't work.
    std::cout << "v2" << std::endl;
    ForEach_v2(words, PrintWord);

    return 0;
}
```

The compiler output:

```
|| g++ -Wall -o test main.cpp
|| main.cpp: In function 'void ForEach_v2(const Container&, Functor) [with Container = std::vector<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > >, Functor = void (*)(const std::string&)]':
main.cpp|116| instantiated from here
main.cpp|96| warning: unused variable 'it'
```

Program output:

```
v1
one
two
three
v2
```

My questions:

- Why doesn't `ForEach_v2` print anything?
- Why does the compiler print the "unused variable"-warning for `ForEach_v2`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You want

```
  inFunctor(*it);
```

not

```
  Functor(*it);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
template<class Container, class Functor>
void ForEach_v2(const Container & inContainer, Functor inFunctor)
{
    typename Container::const_iterator it = inContainer.begin(), end = inContainer.end();
    for (; it != end; ++it)
    {
        Functor(*it);
    }
}
```

Should Be

```
template<class Container, class Functor>
void ForEach_v2(const Container & inContainer, Functor inFunctor)
{
    typename Container::const_iterator it = inContainer.begin(), end = inContainer.end();
    for (; it != end; ++it)
    {
        inFunctor(*it);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is your problem :

```
for (; it != end; ++it)
    {
        Functor(*it);
    }
```

`Functor` now is the **type** of the *function* you passed.

You need to write this:

```
for (; it != end; ++it)
    {
        inFunctor(*it); //note this change!
    }
```

Now this will work!